# Can anyone solve the errors in calculate the arithmetic expressions with stacks?

Tags: java, math, stack

I wrote a code that reads any arithmetic expression in form of a string and returns the result by printing it.
All of this is done with regard to the order of operation (PEMDAS).
As an example the input, "2+7*5+3" should return 40
But the problem is that the program doesn't return the correct result and I don't know what seems to be the problem.
The Code:

```
public class LL {


    public static int calc(String op, int n1,int n2){
        if(op.equals("+")){
            return n1+n2;
        }
        else if(op.equals("-")){
            return n1-n2;
        }
        else if(op.equals("/")){
            return n1/n2;
        }
        else{
            return n1*n2;
        }
    }
    public static boolean check(String oldop, String newop){
        if(oldop==null||oldop.equals("=")){
            return true;
        }
        else if(oldop.equals("+")||oldop.equals("-")){
            if(newop.equals("+")||newop.equals("-")||newop.equals("/")||newop.equals("*")){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }            
        }
        else{
            if(newop.equals("/")||newop.equals("*")){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }             
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ch=0;
        LinkedList<String> op = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> nums = new LinkedList<String>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String exp = sc.nextLine();
        String[] exparr = exp.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0 ; i<exparr.length-1;i+=2){
            nums.push(exparr[i]);
            String oldop = op.pop();
            if(check(oldop,exparr[i+1])){
                if(oldop!=null)
                    op.push(oldop);
                op.push(exparr[i+1]);
            }
            else{
                String n2=nums.pop();
                String n1=nums.pop();
                int nn2=Integer.parseInt(n2);
                int nn1=Integer.parseInt(n1);
                int res = calc(oldop,nn1,nn2);
                nums.push(Integer.toString(res));
                op.push(exparr[i+1]);
            }
        }
        nums.push(exparr[exparr.length-1]);
        String opp = op.pop();
        while(opp!=null){
            String n2=nums.pop();
            String n1=nums.pop();
            int nn2=Integer.parseInt(n2);
            int nn1=Integer.parseInt(n1);
            int res = calc(opp,nn1,nn2);
            nums.push(Integer.toString(res));
            opp = op.pop();
        }
        System.out.println(nums.pop());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check method is wrong. You must return true if the old operation is + or - and the new operation is * or / otherwise return false.

```
public static boolean check(String oldop, String newop){
    if(oldop == null || oldop.equals("=")){
        return true;
    }

    return (oldop.equals("+") || oldop.equals("-")) && (newop.equals("/") || newop.equals("*"));
}
```

Another point is, don't use `pop` method of LinkedList, this method throws an `exception` if the list is `empty`, use `poll` method that return `null` if the list is empty.

The other code is correct.